# cant make a custom array size table in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Hello i want to create an array table who will be 2xX and X is a custom number lets say 20 so we will get a 2x20 array table and all of this in c.
I tried make it like this

```
int j=20;

int table[2][j];
```

but it looks like I cant make it work!!

Comment: In C99 it is possible. otherwise use malloc/calloc

Comment: Yup, just compile with a C99 compiler (i. e. one that is not MSVC or Turbo C).

Comment: C99 has Variable Length Arrays, but you probably don't want to use them (it depends on the upper bound of `X`). You will want to use dynamic allocation

Comment: @EdS. Sometimes VLAs are much superior to dynamic allocation. In the programming language interpreter I am currently working on, I could speed up function calls by 50% by using auto arrays instead of `malloc()`. (Too bad I'm writing in C89, so no VLAs for me, but I would have used a VLA if it was available.)

Comment: @H2CO3: Sure, it just depends on whether or not you can guarantee that `X` is not going to be too large.

Comment: @EdS. Yes, pretty much. (I honestly hope that people don't want to pass a few thousand or even million arguments to their functions :P)

Answer (score 4):

In C99+ you have [Variable Length Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).  However, it looks like you're not using a C99+ compiler (Visual Studio?), and that may be a bad idea anyway as large values of `X` may blow your stack.  If you can guarantee a reasonable size, and if you can use a different compiler, this is a good choice.

However, if you can't use VLA's, you'll need to use dynamic allocation:

```
int *table = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof *table);
```

That just allocated one big chunk of memory large enough to fit your entire table.  To get a particular element, use...

```
int item = table[y * columns + x];
```

If you want to use `table[x][y]` syntax then you will need to allocate it differently.

```
int (*table)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof *table);
/* ... */
table[i][j] = value;
/* ... */
int item = table[i][j];
```

Here, `table` is a pointer to array of `columns` `int`s.